# Webpack with Phantom/Casper/Spooky: Unable to Open File

Tags: javascript, webpack, casperjs, webpack-2, spookyjs

My Spooky/Casper/Phantom project was working just fine. Then I tried to involve Webpack.

When I run the program, I get:

```
CasperError: Can't find module node_modules/spooky/lib/bootstrap/emit
[ { file: 'phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js',
    line: 297,
    function: 'patchedRequire' } ]
```

My file structure is as follows:

- dist/
- index.js
- webpack.config.js
- ...
- node_modules/

In my `index.js`:

```
import Spooky from 'spooky';

const spooky = new Spooky({
  child: {
    transport: 'http',
    spooky_lib: 'node_modules/spooky/',
  },
  casper: {
    logLevel: 'debug',
    verbose: false
  }
}, ...);
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './index.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devtool: 'source-maps',
  node: {
    __dirname: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you try removing this line `spooky_lib: 'node_modules/spooky/',` ?

Comment: Yes, then I just get a different error. It then says: `CasperError: Can't find module node_modules/spooky/lib/../lib/bootstrap/emit`

Comment: I search a bit and found this https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS/issues/179, see if you can figure something out.

Comment: It has something to do with the path. You could try making the path relative like `./node_modules/spooky`

Comment: I've tried that too. In that case, I get `CasperError: Can't find module ./node_modules/spooky/lib/bootstrap/emit`.

Comment: It does seem that I am not finding the correct relative path. But I have no idea which context that path is relative to. I've tried several different options, but none of them take.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135347/discussion-between-ickyrr-and-louis-cruz).